# How to pass oauth token in requests without specifying client id as passed in curl?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to port this

```
curl -L -u 12343434343:x-oauth-basic https://github.com/company/myproj-config/archive/master.zip --output pcfg.zip
```

in python-requests

All options suggested in [requests docs](https://2.python-requests.org//en/master/user/advanced) or  [requests-oauthlib docs](https://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)  mandates passing client-id

Is there a way to achieve what I could do with curl above using requests without passing client-id ?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I managed to find the answer if anyone is interested in

```
   request = requests.get(http_url,
                               headers={
                                   "Authorization": "token " + github_token,
                                   "Accept": "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"
                               })
```